# Font-awesome not loading icon in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome, webpack, webpack-style-loader

I am trying to do a simple require of **Bootstrap** and **Font-awesome** with **Webpack**. I managed to load Bootstrap CSS but Font-awesome is not working properly.

This is what I get as result:

[image]

My codes are given below. What is the wrong thing I am doing here?

Resource: [Github code](https://github.com/arifulhb/webpack-bootstrap-font-awesome-test) available here.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "webpack -w"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.8.4",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.6",
    "webpack": "^1.12.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "admin-lte": "^2.3.2",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.5",
    "bootstrap-webpack": "0.0.5",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^0.8.2",
    "font-awesome": "^4.4.0",
    "font-awesome-webpack": "0.0.4",
    "imports-loader": "^0.6.5",
    "jquery": "^2.1.4",
    "less": "^2.5.3",
    "less-loader": "^2.2.1"
  }
}
```

Entry point: **index.js**

```
var $ = require('jquery');

require('expose?$!expose?jQuery!jquery');

require("bootstrap-webpack");
require('./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css');

require('./resources/css/style.css');


$('h1').html('<i class="fa fa-bars"></i> this is bootstrap');
console.log('hi there');
```

Webpack config file **webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {

    entry: './index.js',
    output: {
        path: 'public/assets/',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    module: {
        loaders: [

            {test: /\.css$/, loader: "style!css!" },
            { test: /\.less$/, loader: "style!css!less!" },

            //bootstrap
            {test: /\.(woff|woff2)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff'},
            {test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream'},
            {test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file'},
            {test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'},

            //font-awesome
            { test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&minetype=application/font-woff" },
            { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "file-loader" }



        ]
    },

}
```

Comment: Did you happen to get this figured out? Ran into the same issue myself and all of the solutions I have found have not worked so far :/.

Comment: @GarrettWills :( still no luck. If I solve the issue, I'll post the solution here. Right now got busy with other tasks.

Comment: I actually ended up figuring out my issue yesterday, but I don't believe it was the same as yours. I'll post a link to my question and see if it can help you.

Comment: @GarrettWills Sure.. please share.. Maybe I can get clue to solve my problem also.

Comment: Check this out. If it helps I can post my webpack config as an answer :).  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33399627/webpack-failing-at-font-face/33400203#33400203

Comment: Did that help you out?

Comment: @GarrettWills sorry didn't get time enough to check. Hopefully in 2/3days I can check it and I'll inform you.

Comment: Alright sounds good, fingers crossed for you!

Answer (score 7):

Check your F12 debug console and see web browser details about error for the given files.

Your web server is not serving .woff and .woff2 files with correct mime type, and therefore they are not loaded at all from browser-client perspective.

You need to modify web-server side to add support for .woff files, for instance on IIS Express in Web.config you should have:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension="woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension="woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
```

and inside webpack.config.js you should have module loader like

```
    {
        test: /\.woff($|\?)|\.woff2($|\?)|\.ttf($|\?)|\.eot($|\?)|\.svg($|\?)/,
        loader: 'url-loader'
    }
```

Comment: `url-loader` instead of `file-loader` was my error. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

I know this is 1 year old question, but just in case anyone end up in this from Google:

There is a known issue from [css-loader generating wrong file paths](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader/issues/280). This won't happen in production build, but still annoying when it render squares in development mode.

Until this issue is fixed, you can disable css-loader source map to see the font rendered correctly in development. Find somewhere in your webpack config that write `css?sourceMap` and change it to `css`.