# Webpack failing at @font-face

Tags: node.js, font-awesome, webpack

I am having an issue using Webpack with FontAwesome. Here are my loaders:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        { test: /(\.js$)|(\.jsx$)/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader' },
        { test: /(\.jade$)/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'jade-loader' },
        { test: /(\.css$)/, exclude: /node_modules/, loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader'] },
        { test: /(\.styl$)/, exclude: /node_modules/, loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'stylus-loader'] },
        { test: /\.(jpe|jpg|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?.*$|$)/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'url-loader?importLoaders=1&limit=100000' },
        { test: /\.jsx$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'react-hot-loader' }
    ],
}
```

And here is the error I am receiving:

```
ERROR in ./~/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css
Module parse failed: /Users/Username/Documents/Project/sub-project/node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css Line 7: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| /* FONT PATH
|  * -------------------------- */
| @font-face {
|   font-family: 'FontAwesome';
|   src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.4.0');
 @ ./client/app.js 83:0-60
```

Has anyone else experienced this issue and found a solution? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Silly error. Removed the exclude from my css loader and got it working.

```
{ test: /(\.css$)/, loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader'] }
```

Comment: not silly at all! I was struggling with this for an hour.